# TCP/IP stack in Verilog

Tags: fpga, verilog, tcp-ip

I am about to write a TCP/IP stack in Verilog. I would have thought this was a relatively common thing, and that implementations would readily be available online.

The obvious Google search for a TCP/IP implementation in Verilog does not point to many solutions. Are there ready and tested TPC/IP implementations written in Verilog for FPGAs?

Comment: Could you use one written in vhdl?

Comment: @apalopohapa: Would prefer not!

Comment: While this is theoretically possible, it's probably not a great idea. TCP is much more a procedural and decision making task, than a primitive/fast/parallel one, so it is more suited to a sequential processor running a program, than it is to state machines and dedicated logic.  You could throw in a processor core, but then you'd have to store the program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They exist, but aren't likely to be free. Typically a processor handles TCP/IP. It may get a hardware assist from hardware, for example the checksum.

An example of a non-free one is from [Hitech Global](http://www.hitechglobal.com/IPCores/10Gi-TOE.htm). It is available in Verilog or netlist. [Comblock](http://comblock.com/com5402soft.html) has one too, but in VHDL, not Verilog.

Comment: Accelize has one, intilope has one... Some good IP(s) will cost you around $30K.